# SVG's not rendering when creating PDFs with wicked-pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, svg, d3.js, wicked-pdf

I've got a number of graphs, generated with D3, rendering on a page in a Ruby on Rails 4 app.

I'm using the `wicked-pdf` gem to convert it to a PDF for pretty printing. Generating the PDF is working but not all of the SVGs are rendered.

SVGs generated through Javascript render correctly, but SVGs that are in the HTML do not.

Here's a JS Fiddle of a test page I created: http://jsfiddle.net/Sidane/162cd58y/

The top circle is generated with D3 and appears when generating the PDF with wicked-pdf. The second circle, which is already in the HTML, does not appear in the PDF. The second circle's markup is identical to what D3 generates for the first circle.

I don't understand why an SVG generated by JS would render but not one which is plain old markup. Ultimately it's the exact same markup.

I'm using `wkhtmltopdf` v0.10.0 rc2 with wicked-pdf.

Anyone able to help?

Here is the full HTML if you want to test passing it into wkhtmltopdf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="target" style="width: 70px; height: 70px;"></div>

    <div style="width: 70px; height: 70px;">
      <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Make an SVG Container
      var svgContainer = d3.select("#target").append("svg")
                                          .attr("width", 70)
                                          .attr("height", 70);

      //Draw the Circle
      var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                               .attr("cx", 30)
                               .attr("cy", 30)
                               .attr("r", 20);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find the answer for it. If yes please let me know how did you resolve it because I am also facing the same issue.